# Android Fragment not showing up after inflation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that I would like to display on top of an activity. This is the code that I'm trying right now...

**MainActivity.class**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
DirectionsFragment directionsFragment = new DirectionsFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.directions_fragment_framelayout, directionsFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    <!-- irrelevant parameters -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/directions_fragment_framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
        <!-- A BUNCH OF CHILDREN -->
    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**DirectionsFragment.class**

```
public class DirectionsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_directions, container, false);

        return viewGroup;
    }
}
```

**fragment_directions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    <!-- irrelevant params -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/directions_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        <!-- irrelevant params -->
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

The activity itself runs fine; when I trigger the fragment to show, it runs through the FragmentTransaction and fragment view inflation fine (confirmed using logs and breakpoints). Since the fragment is being added to a FrameLayout, why isn't the fragment showing up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your **fade_in** animation goes wrong, or ListView empty or adapter not setted

Comment: What is your `layout_height` and `layout_width` of `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView` the **last item in the relative layout will be displayed on the top (over the other members in the layout)**

Comment: @Fr099y I commented out the animation part, still doesn't work. The listview being empty shouldn't matter; it should at least pull up a blank fragment, but it doesn't

Comment: @Sony The dimensions of the MapView are both **match_parent**. Does that mean I should put the FrameLayout last?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, the code you have given does not compile because there is no class or method.

Comment: Also, you should show us what you want the UI to look like. This can be done with a simple drawing in MS Paint or any similar program.

Comment: @darkterbears your  Fragment behind the MapView. What UI want to display? In this case views are stacked and only mapview shown. Or MapView has trasnparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be helpfull

Try to swap your **FrameLayout** and **MapView** in **activity_main.xml**

Your code is working fine but its behind the map view thats why its not showing.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        <!-- irrelevant parameters -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
            <!-- A BUNCH OF CHILDREN -->
        </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/directions_fragment_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add background color in your fragment layout because fragment loaded but transparent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/directions_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        <!-- irrelevant params -->
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, still doesn't work. I even tried making the elevation of the FrameLayout higher than the MapView.

Comment: I tried it again, this time making the MapView disappear (visibility -> gone), and the fragment shows up. Why isn't the fragment showing up above the MapView?]\

Comment: just add background color i think that will work, i just update my ans

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that my test textview actually showed up on a **transparent** background. Thanks!